# Create map based on condition from Future of List in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have method with param type `Future[List[MyRes]]`. `MyRes` has two option fields `id` and `name`. Now I want to create map of `id` and `name` if both present. I am able to create map with default value as follow but I don't want to have default value just skip the entry with null value on either.

```
def myMethod(myRes: Future[List[MyRes]]): Future[Map[Long, String]] = {
  myRes.map (
    _.map(
      o =>
      (o.id match {
        case Some(id) => id.toLong
        case _ => 0L 
      }) ->
      (o.name match {
        case Some(name) => name
        case _ => ""
      })
  ).toMap)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `collect` :)

```
myRes.map {  
   _.iterator
    .map { r => r.id -> r.name }
    .collect { case(Some(id), Some(name) => id -> name }
    .toMap
}
```

If your `MyRes` thingy is a case class, then you don't need the first `.map`:

```
myRes.map { 
  _.collect { case MyRes(Some(id), Some(name)) => id -> name }
  .toMap
}
```

`collect` is like `.map`, but it takes a PartialFunction, and skips over elements on which it is not defined. It is kinda like your `match` statement but without the defaults.

**Update:**
If I am reading your comment correctly, and you want to log a message when either field is a None, `collect` won't help with that, but you can do `flatMap`:

```
 myRes.map {
   _.flatMap {
     case MyRes(Some(id), Some(name)) => Some(id -> name)
     case x => loger.warn(s"Missing fields in $x."); None
   }
   .toMap
 }
```

Comment: How can I log message for invalid ones? Second case need return type of `map[Long, String]` too but in my case it will be just `logger.warn("...")`

Comment: @αƞjiβ see my update to the answer. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Return type is `Future[List[AxiomResource]]` so how we can mapped first case.

Comment: @αjiβ I don't understand what you are asking. Try rephrasing it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def myMethod(myRes: Future[List[MyRes]]): Future[Map[Long, String]] = {
  myRes.map (
    _.flatMap(o =>
      (for (id <- o.id; name <- o.name) yield (id.toLong -> name)).toList
    ).toMap
  )
}
```

The trick is flattening `List[Option[(Long,String)]]` by using `flatMap` and converting the `Option` to a `List`.