# Logging skipped entry while using collect in scala

Tags: scala

Follow up from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801378/create-map-based-on-condition-from-future-of-list-in-scala/34803073#34803073). I have implementation as follow

```
myres.map (
  _.iterator
    .map { r => r.id -> r.name }
    .collect {
      case(Some(id), Some(name)) if id != "" && name != "" => id.toLong -> name
      case _ => Logger.warn(s"Skipping info with id $id and name $name")
    }
    .toMap
)
```

I am trying to log info for the entry that does not matching the condition. How I can access id and name on second `case_`? Any suggestion?

Comment: instead of underscore use any variable. for `xx` and than access to it's data: `xx._1.get => id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the variables in the pattern as you did in the first case:

```
case (Some(id), Some(name)) if id != "" && name != "" => 
  id.toLong -> name
case (Some(id), Some(name)) => 
  Logger.warn(s"Skipping info with id $id and name $name")
```

Comment: It does give the idea, yes. But that idea is wrong :(

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `.collect` for this (the accepted answer will not compile).
`.flatMap` is what you are looking for:

```
.flatMap {
    case (Some(id), Some(name)) => Some(id -> name)
    case (x,y) => Logger.warn(s"Something is missing: $id -> $name); None
}
```